# SQL: sampling the number of non-empty fields

Tags: sql, database-design

There is a table, the table has books and authors. How many authors user adds, is unknown. We need to pull out the names of those books that have more than three authors.
There are, of course, a simple solution: add an extra field with the number of authors of each book. then:

```
SELECT book_name FROM books WHERE count >= 3
```

But suppose the addition of a field "count" is unacceptable. Is it possible to somehow create a query that will return the number of non-empty columns regardless of their number?
At worst possible so:

```
SELECT book_name FROM books 
WHERE author_1 != '' AND author_2 != '' AND author_3 != ''
```

But it is not suitable if the number of authors changes...

I note that I make myself a table, so the authors of the field need not be empty. string, and can be NULL. You can also change the structure of the table. This is the case if the proposed solutions are radical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that *You can also change the structure of the table* and you should indeed do that.

Storing an unknown number of authors in the books table is a bad idea. You should normalize the database and store the books and authors in different tables and use a junction table to connect them, something like this:

```
Table books:
BookID (primary key)
BookName

Table authors:
AuthorID (primary key)
AuthorName

Table books_authors:
BookID (foreign Key to books)
AuthorID (foreign key to authors)
```

Then retrieving information about books with a certain number of authors would be trivial.

See this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/72305/2) for an example.

Comment: Understand.
But if I have 3 authors of 1 book, table "books_authors" will look like this:
BookId AuthorID

Comment: If you have three authors of one book you would have three rows in the books_authors table; one for each author.

Comment: I added an example to demonstrate how it could work.

Comment: Cool,it helps! But I dont understand the importance of this: "inner join authors a on a.AuthorID = ba.AuthorID" ("inner join books_authors ba on b.BookID = ba.BookID" helps us to get 3 rows. Obviously, 3 lines represent the three authors). "having count(ba.AuthorID) >= 3;" - the same. Do we really need "authors" in this query? I am not experienced, maybe, u know better.)
My query:'SELECT book_name FROM books JOIN authors_books ON books.id = authors_books.book_id  GROUP BY books.book_name HAVING COUNT(authors_books.book_id) >= 2'
It works too!) But,maybe,your query is optimally. Please,explain.

Comment: @Boolean_Type You're correct that the join to the authors table isn't needed; I just included it for demonstration of how to connect all three tables. Doing a join with just two tables is fine too as all information you need to answer the query is included in books and authors_books.

Comment: D-a-m-n, tried to vote up your post, but have no enough reputation. Thank u, jpw, u have really helped me.

Comment: +1 for good answer. And @Boolean_Type , even if you can't upvote due to not enough rep points yet, if this solution worked for you (and it sounds like it did), then you should at least mark this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: @srutzky , If I knew how to do it! :-)))))

Comment: @Boolean_Type : Also, there is a link in the top-nav for "help". If there is anything you are unsure of, please a moment to search for help.